# Truncating text when it's in a typescript readonly template

Tags: angular, typescript, truncation

I am trying to truncate text in a popup box, but the text for the popup box is not coming from an html file. The application is an angular application and the file that is building the popup box is an object within a module. Here is the code that is building the popup.

```
static readonly simpleTemplate = new PopupTemplate({
    title: '{name}',
    content: 
       '<b>Address:</b> {address}<br/>' +
       '<b>City:</b> {city}<br/>' +
       '<b>Other:</b> {other}'
    });
```

The "other" field is the field I need to truncate as we anticipate the text could be long. I have tried placing a slice pipe inside the curly brackets but that didn't work. I'm unsure of how to go about truncating this when there is no css file to go with this part of the module.

Comment: When do you want to truncate your text? When the text is longer than a specific length? When the text is too long fit in the Pop up and the pop up width can be different from screen to screen?

Is `other` a local variable in your file? Is `PopupTemplate` a third-party library or did your team built it?

Comment: Our team built it and we want it truncated if it's longer than a specific length. Yes other is a local variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Our team built it and we want it truncated if it's longer than a specific length. Yes other is a local variable.

Then you have two options:

1. Update the PopupComponent your team built to add a custom class to the CSS of the PopupComponent.
2. Truncate the value before passing it into the template.

##### 1. Custom Class:

I don't know what the component is called. Let's call it `PopupComponent`. You and your team can update this component to include a custom class that has all the style you need.

Then in the template, you just need to use the custom class.

**PopupComponent.component.css**

```css
.truncate-text {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**example.component.ts**

```js
static readonly simpleTemplate = new PopupTemplate({
    title: '{name}',
    content: 
       '<b>Address:</b> {address}<br/>' +
       '<b>City:</b> {city}<br/>' +
       '<b class="truncate-text">Other:</b> {other}'
    });
```

##### 2. Truncate the value before passing in:

If you prefer not to update the existing component, you can manipulate the text before passing into the template.

Below, you can shorten the string down and then append the three dots.

**example.component.ts**

```js
const other = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'; // your local value.

const maxLength = 3;
const truncatedText = other.substring(0, maxLenght) + '...';

static readonly simpleTemplate = new PopupTemplate({
    title: '{name}',
    content: 
       '<b>Address:</b> {address}<br/>' +
       '<b>City:</b> {city}<br/>' +
       '<b>Other:</b> {truncatedText}'
    });
```

Comment: we essentially did option 2 where we truncated the value before passing it in. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think for understanding the problem better we would need the code of `PopupTemplate`

But if css can fix it: Why don't use inline css?

```
static readonly simpleTemplate = new PopupTemplate({
  title: '{name}',
  content: 
     '<b>Address:</b> {address}<br/>' +
     '<b>City:</b> {city}<br/>' +
     '<b style="max-width:200px; display: inline-block; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;">Other:</b> {other}'
  });
```

Comment: I hadn't thought to try that, but that would probably work.

Answer (score 1):

The solution we came up with was to add a reference to the other property in the service and then add the substring method. So my code looks like this:

```
properties.other = model.properties.other.substring(0, 30);
```

I suspect that the css suggestion from Jan would have also worked.